# What does the expression (i,j) in c signifies?

Tags: c, operators

I tried executing the following c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
int i=2000,j=100; 
printf("%d",(j,i));

}
```

I gave different values to `i` and `j` and found the output. I always get the output as the value contained in the second variable. Does the expression always give the last variable as a result or does it have any other meaning?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

The output of your code is `2000`, because the comma operator evaluates the two expressions and returns the value of the second operand.  More details can be found in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52558/2172854).